# how to close the gui window when a button is clicked c++

Tags: c++, events, button, user-interface, input

im using dev c++(no qt or visual studio) and have the following button code:

```
  HWND hwndButton = CreateWindowEx( 
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    "BUTTON",  
    "Submit",      
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  
    100,         
    45,         
    100,        
    40,        
    hWnd,     
    NULL,       
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), 
    NULL);
```

i am completely new to gui programming, and i wanted to have the window close when the button is clicked as a test for reading user input.

after reading online it looks like something that occurs within:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

and i have also seen people talk about "OnOk();" but i have no idea where i would put it. how would i have the window close if the button is clicked? where would i have the function to close it? where does the message even go that says the button was clicked? ive been searching for hours on the internet and have had no luck.

Comment: You have to handle `WM_COMMAND` and either send `WM_CLOSE` or call `DestroyWindow`.

Comment: doing `case WM_COMMAND:
       WM_CLOSE;` kills it as it starts

Comment: Read the docs for `WM_COMMAND` and use `SendMessage` only when it's the button you want and `BN_CLICK`.

Comment: In your `case WM_COMMAND:`, you have to place a test `if((HWND)lParam == hwndButton)` (since you created your button without a control ID).

Comment: `case WM_COMMAND:
       HWND hwndButton;
       if((HWND)lParam == hwndButton){
              WM_CLOSE;
       }` still kills it as it starts

Comment: The idea is to compare the lParam with the hwndButton that you received from CreateWindowEx. Save that value so you can use it in the WndProc. If you get WM_COMMAND from your button then you should check for BN_CLICK.